# Isomorphism between Topological Groups.

Tags: homological-algebra, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian profinite group and $G=\varprojlim G_i$ (all $G_i$ are finite).

Then why $\hom_{\text{cont}}(\varprojlim G_i,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) = \varinjlim\hom_{\text{cont}}(G_i,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ as  topological groups.

Comment: That's not true even as groups, you probably confused $\varinjlim$ and $\varprojlim$

Comment: I may be wrong. Can you check profinite groups by Luis Ribes(Lemma 2.9.3)?

Comment: check the answer(https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127291/326275).

Comment: I assume that by $\operatorname{hom}$, you mean the group of continuous homomorphism, isn't it ? Then look for the compact subgroups of $\mathbb{Q/Z}$. Or directly, show that a continuous homomorphism $G\to\mathbb{Q/Z}$ has an open kernel.

Comment: yes, a group of continuous homomorphism.

Comment: How does topological equality follow from your statement? @Roland

Comment: math : I'm sorry I may have spoken too quickly, I was thinking about the general situation and not the specific one